# How to implement custom LogIn with ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a testing database on my local server. In the database, I have a table called "Korisnici" (eng. Users). Using EntityFrameworkCore I generated classes from a database, and here is generated "Korisnici" class:

```
public partial class Korisnici
{
    public Korisnici()
    {
        BankovniRacuni = new HashSet<BankovniRacuni>();
        Dokumenti = new HashSet<Dokumenti>();
        ObracuniZarada = new HashSet<ObracuniZarada>();
        Poslodavci = new HashSet<Poslodavci>();
        PrihodiPoslodavca = new HashSet<PrihodiPoslodavca>();
        RashodiPoslodavca = new HashSet<RashodiPoslodavca>();
        Takse = new HashSet<Takse>();
        Zaposleni = new HashSet<Zaposleni>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    public string Prezime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Korisnicko ime")]
    public string KorisnickoIme { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Lozinka")]
    public string Lozinka { get; set; }
    public int? TipKorisnika { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoviKorisnika TipKorisnikaNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankovniRacuni> BankovniRacuni { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dokumenti> Dokumenti { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObracuniZarada> ObracuniZarada { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Poslodavci> Poslodavci { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PrihodiPoslodavca> PrihodiPoslodavca { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RashodiPoslodavca> RashodiPoslodavca { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Takse> Takse { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zaposleni> Zaposleni { get; set; }
}
```

This class is used as a model for one View called "Index.cshtml":

```
@model Korisnici
<img src="/Content/images/LogoFinal.png" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account"))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.KorisnickoIme, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KorisnickoIme, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.KorisnickoIme, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Lozinka, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Lozinka, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Lozinka, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Uloguj se" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on a submit button, Login action from Controler "AccountControler" is called.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Acces database and search for account
        var dbContext = new AdministracijaZingDevDBContext();
        var korisnik = dbContext.Korisnici
            .Where(k => k.KorisnickoIme == model.KorisnickoIme)
            .Where(k => k.Lozinka == model.Lozinka)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (korisnik != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName" , model.KorisnickoIme);
            

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    
}
```

I have inserted testing data in a database with one record of the Korisnici table.
When I enter correct data into the LogIn form, nothing happens (the user didn't pass login).

Answer (score 1):

just to check, you created migration files and updated the db and so on ?

(This should be in a comment, but I lack the reputation)

also you shouldn't create a new context, but inject it into the constructor of your account controller
( or beter still ... you should inject a repository or better use a unit of work-design and CQRS-design)

Take care and good luck.

so you type ctor tab tab

which would give you

```
public AccountController(){}
```

and than you add a parameter in the AccountController-function like

```
public AccountController(MyContext context){}
```

right click => quick actions and refactoring => create and assign property MyContext

but you should create at least a repositorypattern and inject something like IKorisniciRepository.

It would be easier if you placed your repo on gitHub so I can test before writing.

Try

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly AdministracijaZingDevDBContext Context {get;}

    public AccountController (AdministracijaZingDevDBContext context) {Context = context;}

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Access database and search for account
       
        var korisnik = Context.Korisnici
            .Where(k => k.KorisnickoIme == model.KorisnickoIme)
            .Where(k => k.Lozinka == model.Lozinka)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (korisnik != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName" , model.KorisnickoIme);
        

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

}